# SQL Pass multiple IDs as one variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to pass a theoretically unlimited number of IDs to a stored procedure as one variable and have it return all matching records. When using a list and IN statement I'm getting an error as `ProviderID` datatype is INT and it's treating my list as strings.

```
DECLARE @ProviderList varchar(max)
SET @ProviderList = '1001,1002' 

SELECT *
FROM   tblProviders
WHERE  ProviderID IN ( @ProviderList )

--Error: Error converting data type varchar to bigint. when used
```

Separating the IDs like below works...but as there's no way to know how many IDs will be searched at once it would be messy to have potential placeholder variables which aren't required.

```
DECLARE @ProviderOne varchar(max)
SET @ProviderOne = '1001'

DECLARE @ProviderTwo varchar(max)
SET @ProviderTwo = '1002'

SELECT *
FROM   tblProviders
WHERE  ProviderID IN ( @ProviderOne, @ProviderTwo )
```

Comment: SQL Server version

Answer (score 2):

The best way may be to munge the query string and use dynamic SQL.  This allows the optimizer to compile the query for optimal execution. This approach is to insert the list of ids directly into the string.  Of course, this can be a really bad idea if the list comes from user input, because this approach introduces the risk of SQL injection.

An alternative is to split the string.  The most recent versions of SQL Server (2016+) have `string_split()` (or you can find a UDF on the web quite easily):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM tblProviders p
WHERE p.ProviderID IN (SELECT string_split(@ProviderList, ',') )
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple ways to do this. One is to do a delimited string and then splitting it out. As I'm not sure what version of SQL Server you're on, you can find a copy of Jeff Moden's Delimited String splitter [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).

Then you can do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable MT
WHERE MT.MyValues IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.delimitedSplit8k(@DelimString,',');
```

The alternative is to use a custom table-value type. This is where you can create a datatype that is in the form of a table. So, for example:

```
CREATE TYPE IDs AS TABLE (ID int);
GO

DECLARE @ID IDs;
INSERT INTO @ID
VALUES (1),(2),(3)

SELECT *
FROM MyTable MT
WHERE MT.MyValues IN (SELECT ID FROM @ID);
GO
--Clean up
--DROP TYPE IDs;
```

Any questions, please comment.

Comment: This is the right answer if you are really looking for "theoretically unlimited" ids. In SQL Server (and most databases), a single statement has a maximum length. If you have dozens or a few hundred of items you will probably be okay, but if you have thousands you will almost certainly not be okay, and using table valued parameters is the only (sane) way forward.

Comment: It's also worth nothing the splitter I linked to will only handle up to an 8000 character delimited string.

Answer (score 0):

You can accept input as csv and then you can convert csv to list and pass as in parameter

```
SELECT *
FROM   tblProviders
WHERE  ProviderID IN  (SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVToLIst(@CSV))
```

CSV to list function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CSVToList (@CSV varchar(3000)) 
    RETURNS @Result TABLE (Value varchar(30))
AS   
BEGIN
    DECLARE @List TABLE
    (
        Value varchar(30)
    )

    DECLARE
        @Value varchar(30),
        @Pos int

    SET @CSV = LTRIM(RTRIM(@CSV))+ ','
    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @CSV, 1)

    IF REPLACE(@CSV, ',', '') <> ''
    BEGIN
        WHILE @Pos > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @Value = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@CSV, @Pos - 1)))

            IF @Value <> ''
                INSERT INTO @List (Value) VALUES (@Value) 

            SET @CSV = RIGHT(@CSV, LEN(@CSV) - @Pos)
            SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @CSV, 1)
        END
    END     

    INSERT @Result
    SELECT
        Value
    FROM
        @List

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: It seems like your data needs integers. you can add a cast by in(select cast(value as int) ...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2016 or above, or Azure SQL you can just use JSON:

```
DECLARE @ProviderList varchar(max)
SET @ProviderList = '[1001,1002]' 

SELECT *
FROM   tblProviders
WHERE  ProviderID IN ( SELECT CAST(p.[Value] AS INT) FROM OPENJSON(@ProviderList) p )
```

It is the fastest and most secure method available

Comment: I think string_split is better for this job Although I did not test the performance of both

Comment: Yep also split_string would do too. I still prefer to use json 'cause I can use the ISJSON funciton to make sure I have a valid set of numbers even before starting to use them in the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ProviderList varchar(max)

Declare @sqlstring nvarchar(2000)

SET @ProviderList = '100,200,300' 

set @sqlstring = 'SELECT *  FROM temptable where Num_Key in ('  + @ProviderList + ')'

--select @sqlstring

execute sp_executesql @sqlstring
```